# How can I set up 'maximum length validation for each tag' with acts_as_taggable_on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

I just did set up validations for User model. The codes in my User model are just like this.
If I'd like to add maximum length validation for each tag, what should I add to this?
I also would like to know shorter way to code those whole validations if possible.

```
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
  validates_presence_of :tag_list,
                        :message => "Create at least 1 tag"
  validates_size_of     :tag_list,
                        :maximum => 4,
                        :message => '4 tags maximum'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried many things, and finally I found out how to solve!
This made it working fine:)

```
validate :max_tag_size 
def max_tag_size
 errors[:tag_list] << "2 tags maximum" if tag_list.count > 2
 self.tag_list.each do |tag|
  errors[:tag_list] << "#{tag} must be shorter than 10 characters maximum" if tag.length > 10
 end
end
```

Comment: ah tag_list gives back an array?

Answer (score 2):

```
validate :max_tag_size # HERE WITH VALIDATE - NOT VALIDATES!

def max_tag_size
  errors[:tag_list] << "4 tags maximum" if self.tag_list.split(",").count > 4
  errors[:tag_list] << "tag lenght < 10 letters " if self.tag_list.split(",").collect(&:length).max >= 10
end
```

Comment: I tried your code but I can save tags if they don't match with those validations.

Comment: it looks not working. Indeed it does save record even if it doesn't satisfy your validation check :(